# Object doesn't support property of method 'clone'

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, button, copy, clone

I'm having problems trying to clone a specific section of HTML.

I have a duplicating button that duplicates the last element added, for example a div contains an input box and if they want too add another or they have too do is duplicate it.

This seems to work all fine on every browser apart from Internet Explorer (all version from 8 upwards).

I keep on getting the error **Object doesn't support propert or method 'clone'**

First i have to send the click event of the button to the function 'add_another_repeat' because there could be cases where there are multiple add_another buttons and i must target the closest parent

```
$('p.add_another').unbind('click').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var next = $(this).closest('.option').find('.repeat_block:last').find('p input[type="checkbox"]').attr('name');
  next = next.replace(/elements\[[A-Za-z0-9\_]+\]\[[A-Za-z0-9\_]+\]\[([0-9]+)\]/, '$1');
  add_another_repeat($(this),next);
  return false;
});
```

And the add_another function

```
function add_another_repeat(ev,i) {

//alert('I: '+i);
parent = ev.closest('.option').find('.repeat_block:last');

// make copy and add to DOM
var add = parent.clone();
parent.after(add);

// increment the array keys
var r = add.find('p input[type="checkbox"]').attr('name'),
    pattern = '\['+i+'\]',
    regex = new RegExp(pattern,'g'),
    next = parseInt(i)+1;
add.find('p input[type="checkbox"]').attr('name', r.replace(regex, next));

add.find('input,textarea,select').each(function(){
    r = $(this).attr('name');
    pattern = '\['+i+'\]',
    regex = new RegExp(pattern,'g');
    $(this).attr('name', r.replace(regex, next));
    //$(this).val('');

    r = $(this).attr('id');
    pattern = '\_'+i;
    regex = new RegExp(pattern, 'g');
    $(this).attr('id', r.replace(regex, '_'+next));
});

$('p.add_another button').unbind('click').click(function(){
    add_another_repeat($(this),next);
    return false;
});

// tidy up the first elements
//parent.find('h3 input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', 'checked'); //.attr('disabled', true);
parent.find('p.add_another').remove();
return false;
}
```

The error seem to appear on this line `var add = parent.clone();` but only on **IE ONLY**

Does anyone have some suggestions as to what might be going wrong because i'm running out of ideas

Comment: If you log `parent` to the console, does it have a value or is it `undefined`? If it has a value, is the length >= 1?

Comment: It just says [object Window]

Comment: Time for a JSFiddle methinks :)

Comment: `parent = ev.closest('.option').find('.repeat_block:last');` if i add .html() and do a console log on parent i can output the html i need too clone. But even var add = parent.html(); throws the same error in IE **Object doesn't support propert or method 'html'** ??